# Mongoose iterate and post order find() result array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Based on a list of `ids`, I need to get mongoose data and build a return array in the same order of the given `ids`. Non existing fields must be filled with `null`. Here is my code:

```
export const getByIds = async ids => {
    let results = await Customers.find({ _id: { $in: ids }, deletedAt: null }).exec();

    let rows = ids.map(id => {
        let found = results.find(item => {
            return item._id.equals(id);
        });

        return found ? found : null;
    });

    return rows;
};
```

I'm getting an array of nulls for every call to the function, no matter if the ids exists or not. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: should not u use findone or findbyid  for finding a specific item ?

Comment: _id is specific create by the MongoDB you should specify find you used id that is generated by MongoDB findById()

Comment: Did you get the expected customers in `results`?

Comment: while fetching data from mongodb id is returned as objectId while ids array will contain array of strings of ids you need to change return item._id.equals(id); to  return (item._id).toString().equals(id); for matching them

Comment: Yes, I get the expected customers in `results`; I'm not using findOne or findById because the `ids` variable is an array of ids (I expected to get several docs at once).

Comment: Some more info. Seems that I'm not even going into find, I've put a `console.log()` inside `results.find()` and is not even being printed...

Comment: Don't use map and find functions, just remove it because already you find the document with array of ids only, so the result will give u the document only matched the ids array and use try catch for `Customer.find()`,if any error occurred while finding it will throw error in catch block else u will get the results. Then print the results as `console.log(JSON.stringify(results));` if result not null.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code ,

```
 let rows = ids.filter(id => {
            let found = results.filter(item => {
                if(item._id == id){
                    return item;    
                }else{
                    return false
                }
            });

            return found ? found : null;
        });
```